# Zillo like property details on marker click android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to android. I try to show property scroll view on map marker click from three days. I did not get any solutions.

[Please look this image link](http://s8.postimg.org/smutesvnp/Screenshot_2015_07_04_14_35_21.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! It would greatly help and motivate the community if you could show us effort. Show us what you already tried in code and explain which problems you ran into. Showing that you tried to find the solution by yourself is far more better then simply asking for code.

Comment: Hi Timusan, When i click on marker , I try to show listview in horizental scrool. But it alsways show Vertical.

Comment: Please look at this link http://s8.postimg.org/smutesvnp/Screenshot_2015_07_04_14_35_21.jpg

Comment: Please show your relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is clear. I am using Viewpager for scroll property by help of this tutorial http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/